# how to copy/put Sqlite Database file to Device to test app on it - Xcode

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios7

I have searched everywhere but could not find answer to this question. I have made an app that uses previous build Sqlite database. On Simulator My database file is at 
     /Users/idsMac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/AAAAAAAA-CCCCC-DDDD-7777-PPPPPPPPPP/Documents/

I am using the following code to read this Sqlite Database file.

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"punDictionary.sqlite"];
```

}

```
if((sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &_database)) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Failed to open Database");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Database Connceted ..... ");
    }
```

My App is working great on Simulator .. But When I test it on my IOS Device. It is not detecting the Database.
My question is how shall I add the sqlite Database file to my app to test on Device ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the Sqlite DB file into your project, and copy it into Documents folder if not exist when the app access the DB file.

```
#define DB_NAME @"XXX.sqlite"
#define DB_FULLPATH [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME]


+ (void)createDatabase
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:DB_FULLPATH]) {
        NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:DB_FULLPATH error:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: Which Documents folder?